# My heroku backend data is being created with ID that skip every 10

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-api

My application is in development and I've deployed my rails-backend too Heroku.  However when I look at my heroku backend the id's of all my data aren't going 1,2,3,4,5, extc. but they are going from 1,11,21,31,41,51...extc. I don't understand why this is going on if I'm pretty much using the same rails commands when deploying the database via Heroku. [The api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka5dP.png)

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,

Comment: you can see "Auto increment " in mysql